# Editing element inside another element in css

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons. For now i can only move the position of all of them, but i want to move the specific button "HOME" to the left. 
Here is my html code

```
    <ul class="fullsize-nav-ul">
       <li class="nav-main-item menu-home">
          <a href="http://atlanticsleeptherapeutics.com/?page_id=11">
             <span>Home</span>
          </a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-main-item menu-who-we-are">
          <a href="http://atlanticsleeptherapeutics.com/?page_id=15">
             <span>WHO WE ARE</span>
          </a>
       </li>
   </ul>
```

and css code that i move these two buttons

```
.fullsize-nav-ul {
 position: relative;
 right: 20px;
 bottom: 150px; 
}
```

I tried this way, but it does not work

```
#fullsize-nav-ul li.nav-main-item menu-home a{
 position: relative;
 right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Why'd you change `.fullsize-nav-ul` to `#fullsize-nav-ul`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you changed your selector from a class selector (`.fullsize-nav-ul`) to an ID selector (`#fullsize-nav-ul`). Not sure is that was just a typo, but based on your code you want the class selector.

Then you introduced a space between the classes on the same element in (`li.nav-main-item .menu-home`), which instead turns into a selector for a descendant element (although you're missing the period too so maybe that's just another typo?).

This should work:

```
.fullsize-nav-ul li.nav-main-item.menu-home a {
    position: relative;
    right: 30px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/trLbqeuv/)**

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, if you see the answer form Jay Moy, he says that i don't need many prefixes and that .menu-home a{position:relative; right:30px;} will work. Your and his answer work but which way is better?

Comment: That depends. There's nothing wrong with the selectors in either example, however if you have more than one element with the class menu-home that contains a link, jay-moy's `.menu-home a` will select all of them. It really depends on the other HTML and CSS you have, and whether you need to worry about the rule you're creating being applied to other elements, or if other CSS you have overrides the rule you create by having a greater specificity.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `.` before your `menu-home` css class:

```
#fullsize-nav-ul li.nav-main-item .menu-home a{
   position: relative;
   right: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really much to go on, you should float the li. 
Don't use positioning like this especially on an anchor.

I've attached a working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/0gzx2bru/

```
.fullsize-nav-ul li{
list-style-type:none;
float:left;
padding:10px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not think you can use `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left` declaration when `position` is set to `relative` on an element i.e `{position:relative}`.

To achieve what you want, you might need to set `position` to `absolute` i.e `{position:absolute`}, then play around with the `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` values.

Goodluck!